# How to re-enable a previously installed Nvidia Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, graphics, xorg

Since my previous questions were not answered I will try to ask again more precisely.

I previously had the Nvidia driver installed and working correctly.  Then the ubuntu software update did something which broke it.  In fact, it completely de-configured it so that the standard display driver is used when the computer reboots.  I would like to re-enable the existing Nvidia  driver without re-installing the Nvidia driver.  How do I do that?  This machine is no longer connected to the internet.

NOTE: I am not asking how to disable automatic updates in this question.  I asked that elsewhere (and it wasn't answered).

NOTE: I am not asking how to stop the Ubuntu software updater from breaking the Nvidia driver the next time it updates the system.  That would be nice to know, but I asked that already and did not receive the correct answer either.

NOTE: Please don't make this as duplicate simply because someone else asked a question about Ubuntu and the software updater.  Try to read the actual question and see how it's different and try to realize how annoying it is when users have to spend hours of their own time to correct the problems that other people causing by incorrectly designing software updaters.

Comment: Can you update your question wjth the Nvidia driver version number you keep installing and Ubuntu keeps deleting?

Comment: Stop asking the same question over and over. [Edit] your existing question to include new information or clarification.

Comment: Can you update your question with a screen snapshot of System Settings, Software & Updates, Additional Drivers because you may have Ubuntu configured differently than you want.

Comment: I don't know why you keep saying it's the same question.  There are three different questions:  1) How to re-enable an Nvidia driver.? 2) How to stop all automatic software updates?  3) How to stop the software updater from breaking the Nvidia driver?

Comment: The Nvidia driver is for CUDA 7-5.18.

Comment: I can not update the question with a snapshot of system settings, and you know I can't because I said multiple times that this machine is no longer connected to the internet.  But thank you for asking that because now I know you just are intentionally trying to screw with me.

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia graphics driver in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Same here, I had nvidia driver working ok (installed as adicional driver on system properties...) and last update screwed all that.

Had a login screen but was unable go login to my session, screen flashes black and returns to login screen (lightdm). Guest session reports fail and just does not enter.

after doing an ***apt-get purge nvidia* *** I was able to login again but now if i try to use the adicional nvidia driver it goes all over.

using ubuntu 16.04 LTS to avoid system pimping, i have work to do and wish you guys stop breaking my system so often or at least give me a nice button to go back some bad updates.

Using dual monitor.

P.S. the current driver is the Nouveau (beside that broken nvidia) and it returns from suspension with a scrambled screen, not allowing even the ctrl+alt+f1 (and i wish we could at least copy and paste from any system dialog)